# CKEditor plugin - How to have a span within a span, by using editor.applyStyle

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Currently, I have a custom plugin dialog with drop down box selection, which allows me to insert either **Apple** or **Samsung** tag in between the selected text.

[image]

Here's how its `onClick` function looks like.

```
onOk: function() {
    var dialog = this;

    // Drop down box selection. Can be either "Apple" or "Samsung"
    var brand = dialog.getValueOf('tab-brand', 'brand');

    var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'span', attributes: { 'brand': brand } } );
    editor.applyStyle( style );

    console.log(editor.getData());
}
```

The following code, doesn't work within my expectation. Let's say, I have the following text

**Mary has a little lamb**

### Step 1

"little" was highlighted. "Apple" was selected. OK pressed

**Mary has a `little` lamb**

I would get the following console output.

```
Mary has a <span brand="Apple">little</span> lamb
```

### Step 2

"a little lamb" was highlighted. "Samsung" was selected. OK pressed

**Mary has `a little lamb`**

I would get the following console output.

```
Mary has <span brand="Samsung">a little lamb</span>
```

However, I'm expecting the following output. A span within a span.

```
Mary has <span brand="Samsung">a <span brand="Apple">little</span> lamb</span>
```

Is there any way I can achieve such, by modify my original code in `onOk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor's styles system doesn't allow to apply one style twice, because its first job is to handle styling content. In this case we are talking about inline styles and it does not make sense to apply e.g. the `<strong>` tag twice.

However, the styles system handles styles with `data-*` attributes differently, because these attributes are used to add information to the content rather than for styling purposes. So instead of using `brand` attribute (which BTW. is incorrect in HTML) use `data-brand`:

```
var style = new CKEDITOR.style(
    { element: 'span', attributes: { 'data-brand': 'Apple' } }
);
```

And you will be able to apply one style many times for the same selection.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know appending "data" prefix does make any difference. Thanks.